# Hbase regions always in transition

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

We are running into issues where regions are going in to transition continuously.

Because of this we are having uneven distribution of regions across regions server.

Error in hbase-master logs:-

```
ABORTING region server ip-10-30-1-97.ec2.internal,16020,1572977335091: The coprocessor org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer threw java.io.IOException: No jar path specified for org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer
Cause:
java.io.IOException: No jar path specified for org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.CoprocessorHost.load(CoprocessorHost.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.loadTableCoprocessors(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.<init>(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.<init>(HRegion.java:726)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.<init>(HRegion.java:634)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.newHRegion(HRegion.java:6373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:6677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:6649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:6605)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:6556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.openRegion(OpenRegionHandler.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.process(OpenRegionHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:129)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

logs for Hbase master :- https://pastebin.com/mUMzV6vZ

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Phoenix jar in ALL your region servers of Hbase ?
Seems like you are missing the library in one of them.